# Working with raw output from ffmpeg 'gdigrab' on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture high quality screen recording with the minimum CPU load (what we're recording is already CPU intensive and suffers slowdown if encoding is being done at the same time as screen recording).

I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -t 00:00:05 -i desktop -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec copy -y testing.avi
```

When I open this in Windows Media Player or VLC it sort of works. It's the right size and duration, but the pixels are messed up, as shown below.

[image: output in media player]

Ultimately I'd like to be able to re-encode this to something smaller, again using ffmpeg, but I can't find the right ffmpeg incantation/options for this given the raw input file generated by the first command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output codec of `gdigrab` is BMP.
For grabbing with `-codec copy` we have to store each frame in separate BMP image file.

Example:
`ffmpeg -r 30 -f gdigrab -t 00:00:05 -i desktop -vcodec copy %08d.bmp`

Later we can encode the images offline:
`ffmpeg -r 30 -i %8d.bmp -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y testing.mp4`

---

Using `gdigrab` and BMP images is probably not the most efficient solution.
Modern CPUs that has an internal GPU support iGPU accelerated encoding.

- Intel name is [Quick Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) (QSV).
- AMD name is [Advanced Media Framework](https://gpuopen.com/advanced-media-framework/) (AMF).

Example for using Intel Quick Sync encoder:
`ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw,child_device_type=dxva2 -filter_hw_device hw -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -t 00:00:05 -vf "hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv" -c:v h264_qsv -b:v 5M -pix_fmt nv12 -y testing.mp4`

It may not work if your system doesn't support Intel Quick Sync.
Note: I am getting an error message: "Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter" (I think it's an issue with my system configuration because QSV encoding is not working in general).

The following command is working in my machine (but 20% CPU utilized by FFmpeg):
`ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw,child_device_type=dxva2 -filter_hw_device hw -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -t 00:00:05 -c:v h264_qsv -b:v 5M -y testing.mp4`

---

In case your system has discrete GPU, it may be possible to use the discrete GPU for encoding the video.

- NVIDIA name is [NVENC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC)

Intel and AMD names are QSV and AMF.

---

When GPU encoding is used, `gdigrab` may not be the most efficient solution.
[FFmpeg version 6](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Codec-Packs-Video-Codecs/FFmpeg-codec.shtml) (not yet stable release) supports [ddagrab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ddagrab) for capturing the Windows Desktop.
The main advantage of `ddagrab` over `gdigrab` is that `ddagrab` doesn't transfer the video frame from the GPU to the CPU (and also saves the pixel format conversions).

- Example for using `ddagrab` with NVIDIA GPU:
  `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i ddagrab -t 00:00:05 -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -y output.mp4`
- Example for using `ddagrab` with Intel Quick Sync:
  `ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw,child_device_type=dxva2 -filter_hw_device hw -f lavfi -i ddagrab -t 00:00:05 -c:v h264_qsv -b:v 5M -y testing.mp4`
  Note: I couldn't test the QSV solution yet.

---

When I use `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i ddagrab -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -y testing.mp4`, FFmpeg CPU utilization is around `0%`:

[image]
Note: The above command is working in my system because it has a discrete NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: I tested `ddagrab` QSV solution with Core i7-6700K CPU, and it's not working. I don't know if the feature it not yet implemented, or if it's not supposed to work (or there is some combination of arguments that makes it work).

Comment: me and a colleague are having trouble running ffmpeg `-f lavfi -i ddagrab -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -y -v 40 testing.mp4`, both with nvidia discrete graphics on our laptops. It works when displaying on external monitor but not on laptop monitor...?! Gives error `OpenEncodeSessionEx failed: no encode device`. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Maybe the laptop monitor is connected to the iGPU. Maybe the ddagrab is not yet ready.

Comment: I found discussions about the subject [here](https://forums.tomsguide.com/threads/laptop-using-igpu-instead-of-dgpu-dedicated-and-integrated.431299/), [here](https://www.quora.com/Laptops-that-have-Nvidia-graphics-use-integrated-graphics-as-default-Why) and [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-disable-integrated-graphics-on-a-laptop). In general, the laptop uses the iGPU for saving power, and the dGPU is idled. When gaming, the dGPU is taking the lead, and the iGPU is in "pass through" mode. Look for a way to force your laptop to use the dGPU. For testing, try to disable the iGPU in the BIOS.

Comment: Yes that's what we thought must be the reason - iGPU vs dGPU - unfortunately we have no option in the BIOS to disable the iGPU, but when I tweak all the soft options, I get a different error: `Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_ddagrab_0 ddagrab: Generic error in an external library`